# Why several PHP processes in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

[image: System Monitor]In my Ubuntu's System Monitor i am getting 17 processes for PHP.
They are getting a big part of my cpu and memory.
Some labelled "php" and others "php7.1".
Is this normal to happen? If not what is the suggested solution?

System: Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4.7 with php 7.1 as a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you integrate PHP in your webserver environment.

When 20 requests are handled, which performs PHP stuff, 20 times PHP is executed.

The amount of PHP processes should not be a problem. More interesting is, which PHP application needs much cpu and memory.

Comment: I think it was because of php cron jobs, running every minute